# React 18 react-pdf/renderer - "Can't resolve 'stream'"

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I just started a new project with create-react-app (React 18).
After installing react-pdf/renderer library, having the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/blob-stream/index.js 1:21-47
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in ...

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: react 18 support is not completed, aka PR is not merged. see  [issue](https://github.com/diegomura/react-pdf/issues/1971)